# Multiple columns(for ex: boolean)as slicers in power bi

Tags: powerbi, visualization, multiple-columns, data-analysis, slicers

I was trying to build a slicer in power bi from multiple columns. Here is a sample of my table

| ID | Category A | Category B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | true | false. |
| 2 | false | true. |
| 3 | false | false. |
| 4 | true | false. |

| Category C | Category D |
| --- | --- |
| true | a. |
| true | b |
| true | c |
| false | a |

Can anyone please help me?

I am expecting a slicer dropdown as shown below :

> Category A(only true)

> Category B(only true)

> Category C(only true)

> Category D:a

> Category D:b

> Category D:c

Any help would be appreciated.